# Android - Mediaplayer error PVMFErrNoResources

Tags: android, media-player

I am getting this error when trying to play certain mp4/3gp videos encoded as H.264/AVC.

`06-02 08:46:38.262: ERROR/QCOmxcore(51): OMXCORE API :  Free Handle 586d4

 06-02 08:46:38.262: ERROR/QCOmxcore(51):  Unloading the dynamic library for OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc

06-02 08:46:38.281: ERROR/PlayerDriver(51): Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info PVMFErrNoResources

06-02 08:46:38.281: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1372): error (1, -15)

06-02 08:46:38.281: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1372): Error (1,-15)

06-02 08:46:38.281: DEBUG/VideoView(1372): Error: 1,-15

06-02 08:46:38.302: WARN/PlayerDriver(51): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete`

I have been successfully able to play a lot of other videos that are mp4/3gp of varying sizes, with the same code. Anyone know what exactly this error means?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: do you have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> in your Manifest.xml??

Comment: Yes, like I mentioned, I am able to play other videos with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late for this! but just curious.

can it be that these files where are not 'Hinted'

that is if you are streaming those files which i guess.